# How to assign class to the Splash screen in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen

I m trying to change the class for call the web service from my splash screen class but it fire the error message.

Error is:

> splash screen has not allowed custom class

Comment: A Splash Screen is not supposed to have a class assigned to it.If you want to call web service, do it in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in app delegate

Answer (score 12):

Your launch storyboard is shown before your app has begun executing, so, as the error says it can't execute code.

You can duplicate the scene from your launch storyboard as the initial view controller of your main storyboard, and in this storyboard you can use a custom `UIViewController` subclass and call your web service. Once the call is complete you can perform a segue to your required scene.

Comment: Ya i have create a view controller in main storyboard same as splash screen , used custom UiViewController and called web service as u said once call is completed perform a segue., ITs work

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to add behavior to Launch screens.

You should create another view to add behavior.

For example, this animation behavior is added by using another storybaord:
https://github.com/okmr-d/App-Launching-like-Twitter

After launch screen ended, `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` is called, so you can add your own behavior like this:
https://github.com/okmr-d/App-Launching-like-Twitter/blob/6642733d4d7948fd706950665b8ecc97018b105b/App%20Launching%20like%20Twitter/AppDelegate.swift#L20-L86

Answer (score 1):

You cannot because there is no class assigned for splash screen(Launch screen) in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible to assign custom class to launch screen Xcode gives error Illegal Configuration: Launch screens may not set custom classnames**

We can create our own.